# pyqt multithreading and multiprocessing scheme

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I've a GUI under pyqt5 which has long running tasks like slow graphing functions and some I/O like websockets as well displaying QtableViews with sorting and filtering and the GUI is refreshed every 250ms (or whatever preferably faster) to display real-time data.

In a single threaded application I have undesirable latencies in the display and controls and obviously comes the time to thinking about multithreading and multiprocessing.

I guess I do understand the benefits of each and I'm guessing I need to spread my code both in threads and processes to have an application running smoothly.

What I've in mind is to write a threads manager and a processes manager so that I can push my functions either in threads or processes. The choice which one will be executed as a thread and which one as a process sounds for me should be :

- I/O with long waiting times like communication functions (webstreams, TCPIP requests, disk files read/write, ...) shall be executed as separated threads as they do not require high CPU resources
- CPU intensive tasks like calculations and graphing shall be executed as separate processes.

Is this way of thinking looks like correct or do you have any other recommendations on pyqt code architecture ?

Thanks & cheers
Stephane

Comment: One rule of thumb is to remember that threading shares the memory space and multi-threading creates it's own memory space. If you create a thread, you can access variables and pass data back and forth between your GUI rather quickly because they have a similar scope. To start a multiprocess keep in mind what data is needed for the multiprocess to run and limit how much data you require for the multiprocess so it doesn't start to duplicate a large amount of memory. In multiprocessing also remember you need to us a multiprocessing queue to pass data back to your main program.

Comment: Launching a thread is usually the way to go when using PyQt5, but some libraries like matplotlib are not thread safe and may need multiprocessing to overcome that.

Comment: thanks Andrew. 
My GUI has an heavy matplotlib graph which takes about 300ms to be displayed which slows down the GUI. I was thinking to move the matplotlib graph to an other process because I thought moving it in a thread will not help as the process can only run on thread at a time. I will obvisously face problems with data sharing as until now I'm passing full classes with many objects as this is convenient within the same thread. But one might pass them as well through queues isn't it ?